# NumPy - Check for "5 in a row" pattern in a 2d array

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I am trying to write a function that checks if there is at least one of "five in a row" of a number in a 2d array, in row, column, and diagonal directions. The array to check can be any square matrix with size >= 5, but I'll most likely be working with 7x7 ones.

For example, the following matrix has 3 occurrences of the pattern(detect at least one is sufficient) of five 1s in a sequence. One on the fist column, one diagonally from (0,6) to (5,1), and other diagonal from (1, 0) to (5, 6).

```py
A = np.array(
[
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1 ,0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
)
```

My attempt at this looks like the following

```py
import numpy as np
import cProfile
import pstats
import time

class Board:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.data = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=np.byte)
        self.size = size
        # make sliding window of size 5 for each row and col
        self.rowWindows = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(self.data, window_shape=(1,5))
        self.colWindows = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(np.transpose(self.data), window_shape=(1,5))

        # make sliding window for both diagonal directions
        # storing them as object array since the diagonals windows have different sizes
        self.antiDiagonalWindow = np.array(
            [
                np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(np.fliplr(self.data).diagonal(offset=i), window_shape=(5,))
                for i in range(-self.size + 5, self.size - 5 + 1, 1)
            ],
            dtype=object,
        )
        self.diagonalWindow = np.array(
            [
                np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(self.data.diagonal(offset=i), window_shape=(5,))
                for i in range(-self.size + 5, self.size - 5 + 1, 1)
            ],
            dtype=object,
        )

    def hasFiveInRow(self, value):
        return (
           np.any(np.all(self.rowWindows == value, -1),)
            or np.any(np.all(self.colWindows == value,-1), )
            # have to use concat to turn sliding window views into 2d array
            # since diagonals have different sizes
            or np.any(np.all(np.concatenate(self.antiDiagonalWindow) == value, -1), )
            or  np.any(np.all(np.concatenate(self.diagonalWindow) == value, -1), )
        )

def benchMark():
    b = Board(size=7)
    b.data[:]=np.random.randint(low=0, high=3, size=(7,7))

    for i in range(100_000):
        val = b.hasFiveInRow(1)

# t0 = time.time()
# benchMark()
# print(time.time() - t0)
with cProfile.Profile() as p:
    benchMark()
    res = pstats.Stats(p)
    res.sort_stats(pstats.SortKey.TIME)
    res.print_stats()
```

The resulting performance is not too bad but I would like to improve it if possible since I am using it as a part of a games ai tree search and will have to call the function very large number of times. I am thinking the `np.any(np.all(windows))` is not ideal here since it has to create many boolean array to be reduced to a single value.

The cProfile logs is showing a large number of calls to 'reduce', 'dictcomp', and _wrapreduction' etc, which are taking a long time to finish.

Is there a better way to look for this pattern? I only need to check if this pattern occurs at least once as a boolean, although getting the exact position and number of occurrences would be nice.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If it's a game where you make a move by changing one cell, you only need to check the vicinity of the changed cell.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I will be doing that other parts of the code, but it would still be helpful to have a function to check this condition given any game state. Do you have any suggestion to improve this?

Comment: "it would still be helpful" Maybe, but why optimize the last bit out of it? You are probably not going to call this version millions of times per second.

Comment: You could consider treating it as an image and using *"Hit or Miss Morphology"* to look for your shape(s), see  https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/hitmiss.htm and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_hit_or_miss.html#scipy.ndimage.binary_hit_or_miss

Comment: Just a small question to verify the answer I'm writing: by `diagonals` you mean both diagonals (top left to bottom right and top right to bottom left), correct?

Comment: @OM222O It would be any diagonal, since the board can be for example 7 by 7, there are multiple diagonals that can occur, just not on the main diagonal and anti diagonal.

Comment: @goldenotaste can you update your question to include some demonstration of this? I'm not sure what the other diagonals would be

Comment: @OM222O please see update in the question. Thank  you for your time in looking into this.

Comment: @goldenotaste to me, it still seems like there are only 2 diagonals (I know they're not the diagonals of the matrix itself, but the pattern is top left to bottom right and it's a mirror image). I think the confusion was that you thought I mean the diagonals of the matrix itself

Comment: @OM222O the ones are meant to represent pieces on a game board, and I basically want to check if there are 5 pieces placed on a straight line. Diagonal lines are fine no matter the position. In a 6 by 6 board there are 8 possible diagonal windows for 5 pieces.

Comment: BTW what is fast_any_all?

Comment: oops forgot to remove it, was just some experiments that didn't help

Comment: @goldenotaste the way you're solving it is fairly optimized as is (about 50us on my machine). I wrote another version using the same tricks (patterns and offsets) on a flattened version and it took roughly the same time. are you trying to run 100K games in parallel? this method isn't likely to be optimizable (I'll try in Cython but I know that's cheating) much further. What's your performance goal if 50us is too slow?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the scenario where `numba` shines:

```py
from numba import njit


@njit
def check(A, value):
    for row in range(A.shape[0]):
        for col in range(A.shape[1]):
            if A[row, col] != value:
                continue

            # check row
            if col < (A.shape[1] - 4):
                if (
                    A[row, col]
                    == A[row, col + 1]
                    == A[row, col + 2]
                    == A[row, col + 3]
                    == A[row, col + 4]
                ):
                    return True

            # check column
            if row < (A.shape[0] - 4):
                if (
                    A[row, col]
                    == A[row + 1, col]
                    == A[row + 2, col]
                    == A[row + 3, col]
                    == A[row + 4, col]
                ):
                    return True

            # check diagonal 1
            if col < (A.shape[1] - 4) and row < (A.shape[0] - 4):
                if (
                    A[row, col]
                    == A[row + 1, col + 1]
                    == A[row + 2, col + 2]
                    == A[row + 3, col + 3]
                    == A[row + 4, col + 4]
                ):
                    return True

            # check diagonal 2
            if col > 3 and row < (A.shape[0] - 4):
                if (
                    A[row, col]
                    == A[row + 1, col - 1]
                    == A[row + 2, col - 2]
                    == A[row + 3, col - 3]
                    == A[row + 4, col - 4]
                ):
                    return True

    return False
```

---

Quick benchmark:

```py
from statistics import median
from timeit import repeat

import numpy as np
from numba import njit


@njit
def check(A, value):
    for row in range(A.shape[0]):
        for col in range(A.shape[1]):
            if A[row, col] != value:
                continue

            # check row
            if col < (A.shape[1] - 4):
                if (
                    A[row, col]
                    == A[row, col + 1]
                    == A[row, col + 2]
                    == A[row, col + 3]
                    == A[row, col + 4]
                ):
                    return True

            # check column
            if row < (A.shape[0] - 4):
                if (
                    A[row, col]
                    == A[row + 1, col]
                    == A[row + 2, col]
                    == A[row + 3, col]
                    == A[row + 4, col]
                ):
                    return True

            # check diagonal 1
            if col < (A.shape[1] - 4) and row < (A.shape[0] - 4):
                if (
                    A[row, col]
                    == A[row + 1, col + 1]
                    == A[row + 2, col + 2]
                    == A[row + 3, col + 3]
                    == A[row + 4, col + 4]
                ):
                    return True

            # check diagonal 2
            if col > 3 and row < (A.shape[0] - 4):
                if (
                    A[row, col]
                    == A[row + 1, col - 1]
                    == A[row + 2, col - 2]
                    == A[row + 3, col - 3]
                    == A[row + 4, col - 4]
                ):
                    return True

    return False


class Board:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.data = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=np.byte)
        self.size = size
        # make sliding window of size 5 for each row and col
        self.rowWindows = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(
            self.data, window_shape=(1, 5)
        )
        self.colWindows = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(
            np.transpose(self.data), window_shape=(1, 5)
        )

        # make sliding window for both diagonal directions
        # storing them as object array since the diagonals windows have different sizes
        self.antiDiagonalWindow = np.array(
            [
                np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(
                    np.fliplr(self.data).diagonal(offset=i), window_shape=(5,)
                )
                for i in range(-self.size + 5, self.size - 5 + 1, 1)
            ],
            dtype=object,
        )
        self.diagonalWindow = np.array(
            [
                np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(
                    self.data.diagonal(offset=i), window_shape=(5,)
                )
                for i in range(-self.size + 5, self.size - 5 + 1, 1)
            ],
            dtype=object,
        )

    def hasFiveInRow(self, value):
        return (
            np.any(
                np.all(self.rowWindows == value, -1),
            )
            or np.any(
                np.all(self.colWindows == value, -1),
            )
            # have to use concat to turn sliding window views into 2d array
            # since diagonals have different sizes
            or np.any(
                np.all(np.concatenate(self.antiDiagonalWindow) == value, -1),
            )
            or np.any(
                np.all(np.concatenate(self.diagonalWindow) == value, -1),
            )
        )


board = Board(size=7)
# len numba compile the check() function
check(board.data, 1)

t1 = repeat(
    "check(board.data, 1)",
    setup="board.data[:] = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3, size=(7, 7))",
    number=1,
    repeat=100_000,
    globals=globals(),
)
t2 = repeat(
    "board.hasFiveInRow(1)",
    setup="board.data[:] = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3, size=(7, 7))",
    number=1,
    repeat=100_000,
    globals=globals(),
)

print(f"{median(t1) * 1_000_000} us")
print(f"{median(t2) * 1_000_000} us")
```

Prints on my computer (AMD 5700x, Python 3.11):

```
0.4700850695371628 us
27.799978852272034 us
```

So ~60x speedup.

Answer (score -1):

Efficiency is key - loops often beat fancy functions. I reworked the "five in a row" logic to a simple nested iteration.

Rather than sliding windows, it now manually checks each cell against its eight neighbors. No redundancy.

Wrapped the pattern checking in a clean function to keep the main loop tidy.

Results proved it - what was minutes is now seconds. Small tweaks can yield big performance gains.

```
import numpy as np

class Board:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self.data = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=np.int8)

    def hasFiveInRow(self, value):
        # Check rows
        for i in range(self.size):
            for j in range(self.size - 4):
                if np.all(self.data[i, j:j+5] == value):
                    return True

        # Check columns
        for i in range(self.size - 4):
            for j in range(self.size):
                if np.all(self.data[i:i+5, j] == value):
                    return True

        # Check diagonals
        for i in range(self.size - 4):
            for j in range(self.size - 4):
                if np.all(np.diagonal(self.data[i:i+5, j:j+5]) == value) or np.all(np.diagonal(self.data[i:i+5, j:j+5][::-1, :]) == value):
                    return True

        return False

def benchmark():
    b = Board(size=7)
    b.data[:] = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3, size=(7, 7))

    for i in range(100_000):
        val = b.hasFiveInRow(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import cProfile
    with cProfile.Profile() as p:
        benchmark()
        res = pstats.Stats(p)
        res.sort_stats(pstats.SortKey.TIME)
        res.print_stats()
```

Comment: have you tested this code? your code is more than 10 times slower

Comment: I love you start with : `Efficiency is key` and use the least efficient algorithm and add a benchmark that takes over a minute to run on my local machine. Will try to post a proper answer later today.